# Calculating weights in a NN

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

So I am currently trying to implement my first NN with a genetic algorithm for training and a sigmoid activation function. It's all good but I'm not quite sure in what ranges the weights must be. I've searched some about the question but with no luck. How does one choose the ranges of the weights in a NN? What does it depend on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights can be seen as an intrinsic property of the problem you're trying to solve using the GA/NN approach; there's no general best value fo these, so you're best off studying different weight spans (w.r.t. training sets) with other parameters fixed.

E.g., study different settings for parameter weightSpan in

```
weights \in [-weightSpan/2, weightSpan/2],
```

and let your initial chromosomes describe weights with randomized values in this range. Your squashing function (sigmoid) is used to grade the NN response to the range [0, 1].

Finding an appropriate weight span is, much like setting a value of number of hidden layer, a process if problem-specific testing. ("There is no free lunch").

---

Edit:

I thought I'd add that the easiest way to study different weight spans is probably to set a fixed weight span, say [-1, 1], and study the squashing constant in your squashing function (sigmoid). I.e., study different (non-negative) values of constant `c` in your sigmoid

```
σ(s) = 1 / (1 + e^(-c*s))
```

Comment: Thanks. I expected there would be some sort of a way of knowing what this span would be but obviously no luck for me. Now it ll be even harder to know if what I wrote actually works...

Comment: My advice would be to test quite quickly increasing values of weightSpan, say weightSpan in {1, 10, 50, 100, 300, 1000 ....}, to get some rough feeling of what weights could be appropriate, and do fine-tuning at a later time. Testing the "functionality" of your NN ( -> achieves feasible results, even if they're bad, for your problem) shouldn't depend on the weight span though, unless you have a really non-robust problem with a small space of feasible solutions. Generally bad weights just lead to bad, but feasible, solutions. Good luck!

Comment: Do you know of some easy problem with which to test if the NN works ?

Comment: On the top of my head, try some easy linear regression problem. For example, you could construct some data points that describe, exactly (without noise), a linear function, and use NN to try to find the weights (which you know, by construction) that describe the best fit to these data points (which, by construction, is a perfect 0-error fit). References for such problems in context of ANN should be vast; you could start with the first Google hit I found on the subject: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15381-s06/www/nn.pdf Good luck!

Comment: A note that you are perhaps already aware of: if you use real encoding to represent your weights in the chromosomes, look into creep mutations, as usual mutations might change weights a bit to radically. A good way to study mutations if to disable crossover (or set a really low crossover probability), and just see how the mutations affect your weights during the evolution of your population. Convergence will, of course, become slower, but this test can be valuable for deciding creep rates for specific problems.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try now to figure out if I made anything working at all.